# How to read a point cloud (.pcd) file and send it to a rosbag

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag, ubuntu, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I just started using the Point Cloud Library. I followed some initial tutorial [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php) on how to use it.
I am trying to send a `point cloud` file `.pcd` into a `rosbag`.
I would like the `rosbag` to receive both the `ascii` and the `binary` files. I know that the `point cloud library` has the useful function `pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>` that I implemented on the following example (see below the snippet of code). However I am not sure how to go back to a new line to read the file and make the `rosbag` understand that.
My idea was to create a `void nextLine()` function that does that. But I stopped because I realized that for doing that I will have to write a `.pcd` parser from scratch according to the [structure](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php) of the point cloud file. I am not sure how to move on.

Final goal would be able to read any `.pcd` file and send them to a `rosbag` --> `rosbag play example.bag`

See below the snipped of code I am using:

**pointcloud_reader_node.cpp**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include "../include/cloud.h"
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <memory.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    rosbag::Bag bag;
    bag.open("test.bag", rosbag::bagmode::Write);
    std::string fstring = "/home/to/Desktop/file.pcd";
    Cloud p;
    p.readPCloud(fstring);
//    while())
//    {
//        bag.write("point_cloud/data", p.pCloud2Msg.header.stamp , p.pCloud2Msg);
//    }
    return 0;
}
```

**cloud.h**

```
#include "cloud.h"

#ifndef CLOUD_H
#define CLOUD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <string>

class Cloud
{
public:
    void readPCloud(std::string filename);
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pCloud2Msg;
    void nextLine();

private:
    unsigned int msgPointCloud;
    void packPointCloudMsg();
    std::string path;
};

#endif// CLOUD_H
```

**cloud.cpp**

```
#include "cloud.h"

void Cloud::readPCloud(std::string filename)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> (filename, *cloud) == -1) // load point cloud file
    {
        PCL_ERROR("Could not read the file");
        return;
    }
    std::cout<<"Loaded"<<cloud->width * cloud->height
             <<"data points from /home/to/Desktop/file.pcd with the following fields: "
             <<std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x
                  << " "    << cloud->points[i].y
                  << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;
}

void Cloud::nextLine()
{

}


void Cloud::packPointCloudMsg()
{
    ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
    pCloud2Msg.header.stamp = time;
    pCloud2Msg.header.frame_id = "point_cloud";
    pCloud2Msg.header.seq = msgPointCloud;
    pCloud2Msg.height = 1;
    pCloud2Msg.width = 5;
    pCloud2Msg.is_bigendian = false;
    pCloud2Msg.is_dense = false;
}
```

Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction or providing some example if anyone has ever had this problem before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325030/how-to-read-a-point-cloud-(.pcd)-file-and-send-it-to-a-rosbag/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-08**:
@RayROS: I have the impression you are misunderstanding how things work / go together right now.

If you could clarify what it is that you're actually trying to do, perhaps we can explain.

Things don't get "send to a rosbag". And:

> But I stopped because I realized that for doing that I will have to write a .pcd parser from scratch according to the structure of the point cloud file. I am not sure how to move on.

PCL comes with all sorts of IO infrastructure that can read and write `.pcd` files. I'm not sure why you believe you'd need to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hopefully this will clear up what you need to do to get this working. Firstly rosbags store ros messages, so you cannot save a cloud in pcd format into one. You'll need to publish the point cloud as a `sensor_msgs/PointCloud` or `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` message and use `rosbag record` to write the message into a bag file. It is possible to write ROS messages directly to a rosbag but that is probably unnecessarily complicated in your case.

So you need to read the pcd file as you are now, and then publish it as a point cloud message on a topic. Then you will run your node while using rosbag record to save the point cloud topic to a bag file. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the next line function?

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2